# Comparing 2 strings in a linq to sql statement

Tags: c#

```
 var j = from c in User.USERs
                    where (c.USER_NAME.Equals(tempUserName))
                    select c;
```

this keeps on giving me  an empty sequence

both are just strings im comparing user input with database

Comment: please explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
var j = User.USERs.First(c => c.USER_NAME == tempUserName)
```

or

```
var j = User.USERs.Single(c => c.USER_NAME == tempUserName)
```

or just take j[0] from the result your own query gives you.

P.S. - both First or Single will throw an exception if no item matched the query, if you want to get null returned if nothing was found use FirstOrDefault respectively SingleOrDefault.

---

to broaden the spectrum try something like this:

```
string userToSearchFor = tempUserName.Trim().ToLower();
var j = User.USERs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.USER_NAME.ToLower() == userToSearchFor);

if (j != null)
{ 
  //found something 
}
```

Comment: how would i then single out to use the     j as in j.first() ?

Comment: var j = User.USERs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.USER_NAME == tempUserName);
                
            

            if (!(j.USER_PASSWORD == tempUserPassword))---getting null exception
                {
                    MessageLabel.Visible = true;
                    MessageLabel.Text = "Username/Password is incorrect";
                   

                }

Comment: if (!(j.USER_PASSWORD == tempUserPassword)) null exception

Comment: if you user FirstOrDefault it will return null if no match was found, so first check if j is != null before accessing a property of that instance.

Comment: You might not have any items matching that query. Try broadening the spectrum by making the query not case sensitive. do a .ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) on both c.USER_NAME and tempUserName

Comment: well the problem is now its not getting a match and my data is supposed to match

Answer (score 0):

If it is returning an empty sequence then your where clause is evaluating to false, check what SQL it is generating if you need to solve that problem first.

To answer your question, to get a single element you usually use

[.Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx)
[.SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx)
[.First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx)
[.FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var result = User.USERs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.USER_NAME.Equals(tempUserName));
if (result != null)
{
    //do your thing
}
```

Comment: even when the data i enter is supposed to match result = null

Comment: if you expect null then you can use the Single() method, but why would you expect null?

Comment: no im not expecting a null im expecting it to match but im getting null

Comment: then nothing is wrong with the code. you have to look for you database binding or the according value withing the table is really null

Comment: im using linq and when i use my original code without the where statement it works because there is only one entry in the database for now

Comment: the Equals is case sensitive maybe that is your problem